# I want to know about how to draw a line between two nodes. .

Tags: qt, mousemove, qgraphicsscene, mousepress

simply i explain: first want to mouse press in graphicsscene and release the mouse. that point should be start point. then another plase i should press the mouse and release that will be end point then the line should be drawn. I can draw a line when mouse pressing and moving. but i want to know that abpve mentioned way. please some one help me. i am stuck in this .

Answer (score 1):

You can capture the location of mouse when mouse is pressed on graphics scene by handling mousePressEvent() of graphics scene, and using QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent's pos() method and store it.

Letter whey you detect second mouse click, use first point and second point to draw line.

From you question it looks you already know how to draw line so i will not put anything on that regards.

Something like following,

```
mousePressEvent( QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent * mouseEvent) {
    QPointF pos = mouseEvent->pos();
    if( mStartPoint.isNull() ) {
        mStartPoint = pos;
    } else {
        drawLine(mStartPoint, pos);
        mStartPoint = QPointF();
    }
}
```

Comment: Bro, its bit strange to do. can u give me some example. big help

Comment: How to detect second mouse click?

Comment: you can have one member variable in your class, let's say it mStartPoint, on mouse click you check if mStartPoint is valid or not, if not then its first click, and you save location in mStartPoint. on next mouse click you again check mStartPoint this time its valid, you now know its second click, you use that mouse point to draw line and invalidate the mStartPoint.

Comment: OK, I will try now it. shall i contact u if fail once again?

Comment: bro, still i am fighting to detect first click and second click.any idea?

Comment: Brother, its working. but when i try to insert more than two nodes then occur runtime error. please fix that if u can.

Comment: I think you should post another question, with your code and cause of error. and if my current answer helped you , can you please accept it ?